# config.ru if statement for production

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rack

In my config.ru I would like to setup a code block that will run specific code depending on the environment.

I tried some code but I am not having any success. Any suggestions?

```
if ENV['RAKE_ENV'].to_s.eql?('development')
  Bundler.require(:default, :development)
end
```

Comment: You might prefer doing `Bundler.require :default, ENV['RACK_ENV']` to remove the conditional and handle more cases.

Comment: Thank you for this, I never even though of doing it this way.

Comment: You might have to pass `ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym` though, can’t remember if Bundler will accept a string instead of symbol or not.

Comment: I just checked and the latest version of bundler accepts it without .to_sym

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to check `ENV['RACK_ENV']` instead of `ENV['RAKE_ENV']`.